# jasmine-browser-runner with Rails 5 app. serve command giving localhost didn’t send any data

Tags: jasmine, ruby-on-rails-5

Im using the jazmine-browser-runner test suite in my rails app.

There are two ways to run the test, one is via browser and the other is headless.

If i run my tests via headless, the test suite runs fine.

But if i use the serve command, to view my tests in the browser, I'm getting a strange response from localhost:8888

> localhost didn’t send any data.

I havent seen this before, and have this suite configured in a similar appwhere its working fine.

Has anyone ran into an issue like this before? There's no error output... no logs to check.